# JAVA: get UTF-8 Hex values from a string?

Tags: java, utf-8, hex, converters

I would like to be able to convert a raw UTF-8 string to a Hex string.
In the example below I've created a sample UTF-8 string containing 2 letters.
Then I'm trying to get the Hex values but it gives me negative values.

How can I make it give me **05D0** and **05D1**

```
String a = "\u05D0\u05D1";
byte[] xxx = a.getBytes("UTF-8");

for (byte x : xxx) {
   System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(x));
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't convert to an encoding like UTF-8 if you want the code point.  Use [Character.codePointAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29).

For example:

```
Character.codePointAt("\u05D0\u05D1", 0) // returns 1488, or 0x5d0
```

Comment: Well, do you want the hex values of the UTF-8 (0xD790) or the code point (0x000005D0)?  If you want the code point, convert the bytes to a string with `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` and then use `Character.codePointAt(...).toHexString()` to get the hex representation.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.
`Character.codePointAt` doesn't have a `toHexString` method, it returns an integer. Can you please give me complete example? Thanks

Comment: Oops, toHexString is a static method.  `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Character.codePointAt("\u05D0", 0)))` will print out `5d0`.  If you want to pad it with zeros on the left, try `System.out.printf("%08x", Character.codePointAt("\u05D0", 0))` which prints `000005d0`.

Answer (score 3):

Negative values occur because the range of `byte` is from -128 to 127. The following code will produce positive values:

```
String a = "\u05D0\u05D1";
byte[] xxx = a.getBytes("UTF-8");

for (byte x : xxx) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(x & 0xFF));
}
```

The main difference is that it outputs `x & 0xFF` instead of just `x`, this operation converts `byte` to `int`, dropping the sign.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but it still doesn't give the right values.
I'm trying to reproduce the Hex values of 05D0, the code gives me d7 90

Comment: @thedp It happens because the symbols you encode are represented in UTF-8 by these bytes. If you want to receive the bytes you said, you should use UTF-16.

Comment: UTF-8 encoding doesn't do what you think it does I suspect. Each value is encoded over multiple bytes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description for details.

Comment: Exactly. D7 90 in binary is 11010111 10010000. Here 110 at the start of the first byte is simply an indicator that there will be the next byte. 10 at the start of the second byte says that it isn't the first byte. If we remove them, we have the following number 10111 010000, which is exactly 5D0 in hex. This is how the decoding process works in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this topic to me.